# How do I find correct translations of "reserved names" used in iOS

Tags: ios, translation

I have an app that needs the Location Service to be active and authorized and
if not so a message should appear to the user asking them to enabled and authorize said serivce.

The thing is that my app is translated into 26 different languages and it is important that the localized version of "Location services" in the iOS-settings menu matches the one in my translated popup.

So, is there some sort of Phrasebook for the iOS where one can see which translations being used by apple for different phrases in different languages?

e.g:
en: Location Services
sv: Platstjänster
de: Ortungsdienste

Answer (score 2):

In [this post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/202866-getting-localized-system-strings.html), there is a solution for AppKit.I think it is similar with iOS. Try this

```
NSBundle *appBundle = [ NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.UIKit" ];
NSString *localSetFont = [ appBundle localizedStringForKey: STRING_YOU_WANT_TO_SEEK value: nil table: STRING_IN_WHICH_TABLE];
```

Comment: As far as I understand this is not supported by apple and may therefor not be supported in future releases (could it also be a reason for rejection?)

Comment: It is not in the document, so if you want to use these code in your release version, it may be rejected. The only thing you can do is using it in your debug code and extract the phrases you need.